Library to parse Apex Code
We have a use case where we would want to parse the Apex Code via some library. I came across a library apex-parser but seems like it is owned and maintained outside salesforce. I also came across another library apex-tmLanguage which seems to be an official Apex Language syntax grammar used for colorization. Is there any official library we can use to parse Apex Code?
Use Case
We are building an automation to migrated managed objects to core. As part of the migration we have to change references of Apex classes which might be using these managed objects or has reference to namespaces. We are looking for a tool which understands the grammar of Apex and can necessarily help in doing a semantic code patching
